# How to add a column to a row in a select

Tags: sql

Say I have this table

```
| Col |
-------
| ABC |
| DEF |
```

What query should I write to obtain this result (not literally this result, but a general way to do that)?

```
| Col | Col2 |
--------------
| ABC |   0  |
| ABC |   1  |
| DEF |   0  |
| DEF |   1  |
```

Comment: You would need to JOIN another table to the query

Comment: You need to be more explicit about the logic you want (otherwise, I can just hardcode some values and meet your requirement). Also, which database you are using. And also, showing a bit of effort by posting your attempted SQL is always a good thing.

Comment: Sorry if the question was poorly asked. I'm using redshift. I literally have no idea how to start. I'm not looking for a JOIN, the data in Col2 is not taken from another table, in my case I want it to be 1, 2, 7 and 14 appended to each row in my first table, so as to obtain 4 times more row in the resulting query. The closer I can get to describing it is an UNGROUP BY, but I'm not sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you want to pair two columns, for each combination. Your question is vague and not specific to a problem. That's my assumption.

I guess this query could do:

```
Select Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2 from Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 on 1=1
```

This way, you pair up every row from table1 with every row from table2.

---

Edit, without table2:

```
Select Table1.Col1, Constructed.Col1 from Table1 LEFT JOIN 
(Select 1 as Col1 UNION Select 2 as Col1 UNION 
Select 7 as Col1 UNION Select 14 as Col1) Constructed on 1=1
```

Comment: Thanks that should be taking care of half of my problem (multiplying the number of rows I get), however there is no Table2, I need it to be 0 and 1 (or in the actual case, 1, 2, 7 and 14) appended to each row.

Comment: See my edit, it does not contain table2 as specified for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this should give you the results you're looking for:

```
Select      Col, Col2
From        YourTable
Cross Join  (Select 0 As Col2 Union Select 1 As Col2) X
Order By    Col, Col2
```

Comment: sorry if the question was unclear, Cross Join seems to be the answer indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test query, is this what you want?

```
select * from
(select col1, 0 b from table) table1
union all (select col1, 1 b from table) order by 1;
```